# Is it beneficial to reduce number of DB calls by merging conditions covered by PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring

I've given a very ugly piece of code which combines PHP loops and SQL queries to retrieve some IDs and I have to refractor. My plan is to merge the PHP iteration to the queries, but I was wondering if **a.** doing this affect the result and **b.** it really has good impact on the performance.

The following is a gesture of the current state of the script:

```
$additional_conditions = [
    "test_column1 = 'b1' OR test_column1 = 'b2' ",
    "test_column2 = 'c1' OR test_column2 = 'c2' ",
    "test_column3 = 'd1' OR test_column3 = 'd2' ",
    "test_column4 = 'e1' OR test_column4 = 'e2' ",
    "test_column5 = 'f1' OR test_column5 = 'f2' ",
];


$query = 'SELECT * from test_table WHERE test_column = 1 AND %s';

foreach ($additional_conditions as $additional_condition)
{
    $result = mysqlQuery(sprintf($query, $additional_condition));

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        // do something with the data
    }
}
```

which I'm thinking to change it to:

```
$query = <<<QUERY
    SELECT * from test_table WHERE test_column = 1 AND (
        (test_column1 = 'b1' OR test_column1 = 'b2') OR
        (test_column2 = 'c1' OR test_column2 = 'c2') OR
        (test_column3 = 'd1' OR test_column3 = 'd2') OR
        (test_column4 = 'e1' OR test_column4 = 'e2') OR
        (test_column5 = 'f1' OR test_column5 = 'f2')
    )

QUERY;

$result = mysqlQuery($query);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // do something with the data
}
```

Comment: What is `test_column1`?

Comment: these are just sample table columns/fields, in the original script there are a bunch of conditions stored in a list as demonstrated in the first panel and a using a loop it will execute the query for each and act on the result. in the second panel we included all those conditions in the single query which need to be executed only once

Comment: Yes, if you can get data in one SQL, do not call in rwo SQLs

Answer (score 1):

Your database engine will optimize the query to make it more efficient. It is usually better to perform a heavy database query than a number of dummy queries.